# Outlook and AutoHotkey, how to output Unicode symbols without switching the font?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, fonts, autohotkey, unicode

I have a keyboard binding to output an Unicode `RIGHTWARDS ARROW` (code 2192) when typing `->`:

```
::->::{U+2192}
```

It works great everywhere (Notepad(++), vscode, ...) except in Outlook (new mail composition) where the font after the symbol is changed twice.

Specifically in my case, the base font for my emails is *Verdana*. When typing `->`, the → is output, then a space in *Calibri* or *Times Roman* and then the font switches to *Arial*.

Is there a reason for this weird behaviour, and most importantly, is there a way to output a raw `→` and stay with the same font as before?

Comment: Outlook - and probably the other Office applications - will use font-substitution if the character you're attempting to type doesn't exist in the current font (or if Outlook/Office doesn't believe that it exists in the current font). Unfortunately, there's an unacknowledged bug in the font-substitution routines that results in the original font not being properly restored in all cases. It looks like you've hit that bug.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Use small trick: Propagate current font further and then return to type the arrow.

Type one space ahead, then back up, type the arrow and return where you started. In other words:

```
::->::{Space}{Left}{U+2192}{Right}
```

Comment: Very good idea! Thanks!